# How to get iSCSI Initiator name in Windows and Linux using C++

Tags: c++, windows, linux, iscsi

Through my C++ code, I want to get the iSCSI initiator name on both Windows and Linux system (the system where iSCSI initiator in present).

On Windows, I found that there is **Iscsidsc.dll** library which seems to have functions for getting the iSCSI initiator name.

So I want to know

- Whether there is some common library for both Windows and Linux which can return the iSCSI initiator name?
- If there is no such common library then how to get the iSCSI initiator name on Windows? Is **Iscsidsc.dll** the correct library?
- If there is no such common library then how to get the iSCSI initiator name on **Linux**?

Please help me to find the answers of above queries.

Thanks,

Nitin

Answer (score 1):

#2. Yes, iscsidsc.dll is a correct library for Windows. Call GetIscsiInitiatorNodeName (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870785(v=vs.85).aspx).